# Get value from array in JSON from an external api

Tags: java, arrays, json, spring

After being introduced to Spring, I decided that I would create my currency calculator from an external API. I encountered a problem retrieving data from an array. I don't know how to retrieve the "mid" data from *OpenCurrencyRatesDto.java*. I am using IntelliJ with Gradle. Please understand and thank you in advance for your help.

**CurrencyClient.java**

```
package com.arturu.currencycalculator1.client.currency;

import com.arturu.currencycalculator1.model.currencyDTO;
import com.arturu.currencycalculator1.webclient.currency.dto.OpenCurrencyCurrencyDto;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
@Component
public class CurrencyClient {


    private static final String NBP_PL = "http://api.nbp.pl";
    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    public currencyDTO getCurrencyValue(String symbol) {
        OpenCurrencyCurrencyDto openCurrencyCurrencyDto = callGetMethod("/api/exchangerates/rates/a/{symbol}/?format=json",
                OpenCurrencyCurrencyDto.class,
                symbol);
        return currencyDTO.builder()
                .mid(openCurrencyCurrencyDto.getRates().getMid())
                .build();

    }

    private <T> T callGetMethod(String url, Class<T> responseType, Object...objects) {
        return restTemplate.getForObject(NBP_PL + url,
                responseType, objects);
    }

}
```

**OpenCurrencyCurrencyDto.java**

```
package com.arturu.currencycalculator1.webclient.currency.dto;

import lombok.Getter;

@Getter
public class OpenCurrencyCurrencyDto {
    private OpenCurrencyRatesDto rates;
}
```

**OpenCurrencyRatesDto.java**

```
package com.arturu.currencycalculator1.webclient.currency.dto;

import lombok.Getter;

@Getter

public class OpenCurrencyRatesDto {
    private double mid;

}
```

**API**

[image]

**Error**

[image]

> ERROR 16640 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].
> [dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet
> [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed:
> org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [class com.arturu.currencycalculator1.webclient.currency.dto.OpenCurrencyCurrencyDto] and content type [application/json;charset=utf-8]] with root cause

Answer (score 0):

Tried to replicate your question,
the issue may be with the structure of your `OpenCurrencyCurrencyDto`,

Redefine `rates` in `OpenCurrencyCurrencyDto` to type `List<OpenCurrencyRatesDto>`:

```
public class OpenCurrencyCurrencyDto {
    private List<OpenCurrencyRatesDto> rates;
}
```

You would need to update your `currencyDto` *(which may need to  be capitalised btw)*, as the response from the external API returns a list of rates, which means you should either

1. choose which `mid` you are setting to your `currencyDto`
2. set list of `mid` in your `currencyDto`

Hope it helps.